# Handling Firebase Remote Config crashes

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I have been working with Firebase remote config for a while in my app, but I notice that when an error data is pushed from Firebase console and app crashes, there is no way you can undo the effect on app crash even after you have corrected the sent data from firebase console. Unless you clear the App cache from Phone or reinstall again the app will crash on starting.

Please is there a way to handle this issue as it will be a total devastating if someone mistakenly crashes his app from Firebase console, users might not go back through this technicalities.

Comment: What kind of data is stored by you in Firebase Remote Config? Is it simply true or false or what?

Comment: I use firebase remote config to change a text color, primary toolbar color etc. 
For example, 
My design is, the remote config fetches a #fff that overrides the default #ffc000 of a text when configuration_turns=true else when configuration_turns=false maintain default value.

When I mistakenly type 4546 which is an error for a color (without the hash value), the app crashes, and fails to load up return to a valid value unless I clear app cache from settings or re-install app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you can arrange for your app to complete a Remote Config fetch, followed by apply of those changes, **before** the crashing code executes, there's really nothing you can do without publishing a new version of your app that can defend against invalid data coming from Remote Config.

**You should always be checking for bad data, even if it comes from Remote Config.  Because people do make mistakes.**

If you are worried about this in the future, maybe you could code up something where you send a Cloud Message to tell your app to force a fetch, then apply the changes immediately, so that next time the app is launched, it can execute without being affected by bad data.

Comment: Thank you! I never thought of both ways like checking for bad data before accept config and also changing the logic my app starts with to override this crash error. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using getString() method to get the value of color's hash code. Since the key:value pairs in Remote Config are pure strings, we have no way of understanding what is the correct value in your keys. Is #ffffff correct or 12345 is correct.

When fetching non trivial & business critical values, please process them for validation before you use the values in your codebase.

That said, bringing data types to Remote Config is on our roadmap. It will still not prevent you from making the mistake you mentioned above.

Thanks